# Return a Pointer in C (Segment Fault Troubleshoot)

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

*(I am new to c language)*

I am trying to return a pointer from a function, and I am getting `segment fault` error. I know its usually because running loop unnecessary times or trying to access unnecessary locations in the memory. I spent whole last night and this morning but still couldn't figure out the silly mistake I am making.

This is the function that I am trying get the pointer

```
char *mySubStr(char *find, char *search){
    char *p, *q, *i;
    int count;
    p = find;
    q = search;
    int size = strlen(q);

    char *start = malloc ( size + 1 );

    for (i=p; i != '\0'; i++){
            if (i == q){
                    count = 0;
                    start = i;
                    while(i == q){
                            i++; count++; q++;
                            if(count == size) return start;
                    }
                    q = search;
            }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

and thats my `main` function,

```
int main(){
    int dump;
    char str1[100], str2[100], *start;
    printf("Enter 1st String: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", str1);
    dump = getchar();
    printf("Enter 2nd String: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", str2);
    dump = getchar();

    *start = *mySubStr(str1, str2);

    printf("start: %s\n", start);
}
```

I am sure I am making some stupid mistake as usual, no surprises there.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhas `i != '\0'` --> `*i != '\0'`? And please dont write things like `i++; count++; q++;`, if you write `i++; count++; i++;` it would be correct but it would look like **undefined behavior** if you look at it quickly.

Comment: nope, still getting the same error :/

Comment: `*start = *mySubStr(str1, str2);` → `start = mySubStr(str1, str2);`. Also, male sure `start` isn't `NULL` before printing. And don't forget to `free` it.

Comment: @CoolGuy, that solves it thank you :) but why its always returning `NULL` instead of `start`?

Comment: There are a *lot* of other problems in your code... What are you trying to achieve? And what does `mySubStr` need to return?

Comment: Talha, what options are you passing to your compiler when you build? It should have complained a few times when you compiled. Make _sure_ you turn on warnings, and (while learning) ask your compiler for _all_ warnings to be displayed. This gives you a warning that's much simpler to search for (it's MUCH harder to search for behavior of crashing programs), and sets your expectations correctly that the program is probably going to explode :)

Comment: @TimPost, `gcc -Wall filename.c` and its not giving me any errors or warnings. The only warning I am getting is about the `dump` variable, that I am not being worried about for now.

Comment: @TalhaTemuri Try -Wextra ;) It's strange that GCC didn't complain about a variety of things here.

Comment: @TimPost, absolutely no warnings with `-Wextra`

Comment: @CoolGuy, I am trying to return a pointer to the first location where the string starts, if the two strings matches.

Lets say I have `str1 = "Hello World"` and `str2 = "World"`, as `str2` is in `str1` I want to return a pointer that points to the `W` of `str1`. I hope that make senes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank so much for all those who has pointed out the silly mistake that I was making `*start = *mySubStr(str1, str2);`, even though that is not something I was looking for, but still I gave everyone a thumbs up. As I was trying everything I possibly could to make it work, and I forgot to remove `*` before posting my question here (Sorry, I know thats silly of me).

I wanted to return a pointer from the function `mySubStr` if the two strings matches otherwise `NULL`. Lets say I have `str1 = "Hello World"` and `str2 = "World"`, as `str2` is in `str1` then it should return a pointer that points to the `W` of `str1`. I hope that make sense :) And that is how I finally able to achieve it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *mySubStr(char *find, char *search);
char *mySubStr(char *find, char *search){
    char *p, *q, *start;
    int count, i;
    p = find;
    q = search;
    int size = strlen(q);

    for (i=0; i < strlen(p); i++){
        count = 0;
        if (p[i] == q[count]){
            start = &p[i];
            while(p[i] == q[count]){
                i++; count++;
                if(count == size) return start;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(){
    int dump;
    char str1[100], str2[100], *start;
    printf("Enter 1st String: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", str1);
    dump = getchar();
    printf("Enter 2nd String: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", str2);
    dump = getchar();

    start = mySubStr(str1, str2);

    printf("start: %s\n", start);
}
```

Thank so much everyone :)

Answer (score 7):

You have *undefined behavior* in this line:

```
*start = *mySubStr(str1, str2);
```

The variable `start` is uninitialized and will have an indeterminate value, so it can point just about anywhere and most likely somewhere where you can't write. The other problem happens if `mySubStr` returns `NULL` in which case `*mySubStr(...)` will dereference a null pointer which is also undefined.

What you want here is *not* dereferencing, just plain assignment:

```
start = mySubStr(str1, str2);
```

Remember to check for the null pointer being returned before you use the pointer, and also remember that you need to `free` the memory once you're done with it.

---

Oh, actually *don't* `free` the pointer returned by `mySubStr` because the pointer it returns is *not* the memory you have allocated, because of

```
start = i;
```

you *lose* the original pointer that you allocated.

If you want to create a completely new string, you should copy the sub-string you extract, which you should do inside the nested `while` loop. Remember to terminate the string.

Answer (score 2):

The following is wrong:

```
*start = *mySubStr(str1, str2);
```

You should use:

```
start = mySubStr(str1, str2);
```

Further, as a good practice, you should initialize `start` to `NULL` and test its value before you use it. Also, `main()` returns an `int`, but you do not return any value on exit. Use return values to deal with error and success conditions.

Finally, if you allocate non-zero space for `start`, you should `free` it when you're done with this chunk of memory, to avoid leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `mySubStr()` function is really ugly and formatted in such a way that it's quite hard to read, and has some mistakes like `i != '\0'` which apparently has to be `*i != '\0'` if I understand it correctly, but **MOST IMPORTANTLY IT ALWAYS RETURNS `NULL`.**

Try fixing all the problems

```
return start;
```

instead of

```
return NULL;
```

This means that `printf()` might be trying to dereference a `NULL`, pointer. Your `mySubStr()` function is leaking `start` because there is no way that you can `free()` it anymore. And also, this

```
*start = *mySubStr(str1, str2);
```

is wrong, you are dereferencing the `NULL` pointer returned by `mySubStr()` and also you are not assigning the pointer to the substring you want to return from the function, this would just assign the first element.

You are also dereferencing `start` which is an uninitialized pointer yet another reason for *Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: I am not getting any compilation errors, and I am using `gcc`

Comment: @TalhaTemuri You are right, all the things you did even though they are not the things you have to do, would never trigger a warning.

Comment: still no warnings, its just telling me that I haven't used `dump` variable.

Comment: @TalhaTemuri Yes I just realized that, but still your `scanf()` format is wrong try `%[^\n]%*c` and remove the `dump` variable completely, it will do what you want. The `s` there `%[^\n]s` is not needed.

Comment: dude, I was right. It should be `i == '\0'` not `*i == '\0'`, and `i == '\0'` is working fine for me. And yes its now returning me the desire results.

Comment: No, because `i` is a pointer. If you want to check whether `i` is `NULL` then use `i == NULL`, if you want to check for the *null* terminator use `*i == '\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other severe problems:

The function also seems to return uninitialized memory, at no point is anything copied into memory pointed to by `start`.

Is the function missing a copy operation from `char *search` to `char* memory`?

The pointer `start` in the function seems to be changed and then returned. This will cause a memory leak.